# Checking Valid Country Names Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I got a column that contains countries. I was wondering, is there a way to check if the column contains any invalid country names and print them out?

```
             Column1
             Hong Kong
             United States of America
             Malaysia 
             Thailand
             Canada
             Indi 
             Koreai
             Japan
             Australia
```

My desire result will be

```
             Column1 
             Indi 
             Koreai
```

Comment: What are your thoughts to solve this problem?
Do you have a list containing all countries of the world? Then yes.
Do you expect Python to know / google a list of all countries in the world? Then no.

Comment: You need to provide a valid list or function to validate the data

Comment: No i don't, Is there anywhere i can find the list?

Comment: i do this in php, but this is my **[source of truth](http://country.io/iso3.json)**. There are a few web services there : iso3, names, continent,currency.

Comment: @nostradamus you are aptly named ;)

Comment: I wish programming was like this. You want to do something and Python or your favourite language knows exactly what you want to do and how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with pycountry is it a module - however it is inaccurate !! it contains 249 countries - where as the UN currently lists 241.

This is what I currently use

```
class nation(object):
    def __init__(self, un_code, un_name, un_3_str):
        self._code = int(un_code)
        self._name = un_name
        self._code3 = un_3_str

    @property
    def numeric(self):
        return self._code

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @property
    def code(self):
        return self._code3


class UN_db(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.UN = [("4", "Afghanistan", "AFG"),
                   ("248", "Aland Islands", "ALA"),
                   ("8", "Albania", "ALB"),
                   ("12", "Algeria", "DZA"),
                   ("16", "American Samoa", "ASM"),
                   ("20", "Andorra", "AND"),
                   ("24", "Angola", "AGO"),
                   ("660", "Anguilla", "AIA"),
                   ("28", "Antigua and Barbuda", "ATG"),
                   ("32", "Argentina", "ARG"),
                   ("51", "Armenia", "ARM"),
                   ("533", "Aruba", "ABW"),
                   ("36", "Australia", "AUS"),
                   ("40", "Austria", "AUT"),
                   ("31", "Azerbaijan", "AZE"),
                   ("44", "Bahamas", "BHS"),
                   ("48", "Bahrain", "BHR"),
                   ("50", "Bangladesh", "BGD"),
                   ("52", "Barbados", "BRB"),
                   ("112", "Belarus", "BLR"),
                   ("56", "Belgium", "BEL"),
                   ("84", "Belize", "BLZ"),
                   ("204", "Benin", "BEN"),
                   ("60", "Bermuda", "BMU"),
                   ("64", "Bhutan", "BTN"),
                   ("68", "Bolivia (Plurinational State of)", "BOL"),
                   ("535", "Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba", "BES"),
                   ("70", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "BIH"),
                   ("72", "Botswana", "BWA"),
                   ("76", "Brazil", "BRA"),
                   ("92", "British Virgin Islands", "VGB"),
                   ("96", "Brunei Darussalam", "BRN"),
                   ("100", "Bulgaria", "BGR"),
                   ("854", "Burkina Faso", "BFA"),
                   ("108", "Burundi", "BDI"),
                   ("132", "Cabo Verde", "CPV"),
                   ("116", "Cambodia", "KHM"),
                   ("120", "Cameroon", "CMR"),
                   ("124", "Canada", "CAN"),
                   ("136", "Cayman Islands", "CYM"),
                   ("140", "Central African Republic", "CAF"),
                   ("148", "Chad", "TCD"),
                   ("830", "Channel Islands", ""),
                   ("152", "Chile", "CHL"),
                   ("156", "China", "CHN"),
                   ("344", "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region", "HKG"),
                   ("446", "China, Macao Special Administrative Region", "MAC"),
                   ("170", "Colombia", "COL"),
                   ("174", "Comoros", "COM"),
                   ("178", "Congo", "COG"),
                   ("184", "Cook Islands", "COK"),
                   ("188", "Costa Rica", "CRI"),
                   ("384", "Cote d'Ivoire", "CIV"),
                   ("191", "Croatia", "HRV"),
                   ("192", "Cuba", "CUB"),
                   ("531", "Curacao", "CUW"),
                   ("196", "Cyprus", "CYP"),
                   ("203", "Czech Republic", "CZE"),
                   ("408", "Democratic People's Republic of Korea", "PRK"),
                   ("180", "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "COD"),
                   ("208", "Denmark", "DNK"),
                   ("262", "Djibouti", "DJI"),
                   ("212", "Dominica", "DMA"),
                   ("214", "Dominican Republic", "DOM"),
                   ("218", "Ecuador", "ECU"),
                   ("818", "Egypt", "EGY"),
                   ("222", "El Salvador", "SLV"),
                   ("226", "Equatorial Guinea", "GNQ"),
                   ("232", "Eritrea", "ERI"),
                   ("233", "Estonia", "EST"),
                   ("231", "Ethiopia", "ETH"),
                   ("234", "Faeroe Islands", "FRO"),
                   ("238", "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)", "FLK"),
                   ("242", "Fiji", "FJI"),
                   ("246", "Finland", "FIN"),
                   ("250", "France", "FRA"),
                   ("254", "French Guiana", "GUF"),
                   ("258", "French Polynesia", "PYF"),
                   ("266", "Gabon", "GAB"),
                   ("270", "Gambia", "GMB"),
                   ("268", "Georgia", "GEO"),
                   ("276", "Germany", "DEU"),
                   ("288", "Ghana", "GHA"),
                   ("292", "Gibraltar", "GIB"),
                   ("300", "Greece", "GRC"),
                   ("304", "Greenland", "GRL"),
                   ("308", "Grenada", "GRD"),
                   ("312", "Guadeloupe", "GLP"),
                   ("316", "Guam", "GUM"),
                   ("320", "Guatemala", "GTM"),
                   ("831", "Guernsey", "GGY"),
                   ("324", "Guinea", "GIN"),
                   ("624", "Guinea-Bissau", "GNB"),
                   ("328", "Guyana", "GUY"),
                   ("332", "Haiti", "HTI"),
                   ("336", "Holy See", "VAT"),
                   ("340", "Honduras", "HND"),
                   ("348", "Hungary", "HUN"),
                   ("352", "Iceland", "ISL"),
                   ("356", "India", "IND"),
                   ("360", "Indonesia", "IDN"),
                   ("364", "Iran (Islamic Republic of)", "IRN"),
                   ("368", "Iraq", "IRQ"),
                   ("372", "Ireland", "IRL"),
                   ("833", "Isle of Man", "IMN"),
                   ("376", "Israel", "ISR"),
                   ("380", "Italy", "ITA"),
                   ("388", "Jamaica", "JAM"),
                   ("392", "Japan", "JPN"),
                   ("832", "Jersey", "JEY"),
                   ("400", "Jordan", "JOR"),
                   ("398", "Kazakhstan", "KAZ"),
                   ("404", "Kenya", "KEN"),
                   ("296", "Kiribati", "KIR"),
                   ("414", "Kuwait", "KWT"),
                   ("417", "Kyrgyzstan", "KGZ"),
                   ("418", "Lao People's Democratic Republic", "LAO"),
                   ("428", "Latvia", "LVA"),
                   ("422", "Lebanon", "LBN"),
                   ("426", "Lesotho", "LSO"),
                   ("430", "Liberia", "LBR"),
                   ("434", "Libya", "LBY"),
                   ("438", "Liechtenstein", "LIE"),
                   ("440", "Lithuania", "LTU"),
                   ("442", "Luxembourg", "LUX"),
                   ("450", "Madagascar", "MDG"),
                   ("454", "Malawi", "MWI"),
                   ("458", "Malaysia", "MYS"),
                   ("462", "Maldives", "MDV"),
                   ("466", "Mali", "MLI"),
                   ("470", "Malta", "MLT"),
                   ("584", "Marshall Islands", "MHL"),
                   ("474", "Martinique", "MTQ"),
                   ("478", "Mauritania", "MRT"),
                   ("480", "Mauritius", "MUS"),
                   ("175", "Mayotte", "MYT"),
                   ("484", "Mexico", "MEX"),
                   ("583", "Micronesia (Federated States of)", "FSM"),
                   ("492", "Monaco", "MCO"),
                   ("496", "Mongolia", "MNG"),
                   ("499", "Montenegro", "MNE"),
                   ("500", "Montserrat", "MSR"),
                   ("504", "Morocco", "MAR"),
                   ("508", "Mozambique", "MOZ"),
                   ("104", "Myanmar", "MMR"),
                   ("516", "Namibia", "NAM"),
                   ("520", "Nauru", "NRU"),
                   ("524", "Nepal", "NPL"),
                   ("528", "Netherlands", "NLD"),
                   ("540", "New Caledonia", "NCL"),
                   ("554", "New Zealand", "NZL"),
                   ("558", "Nicaragua", "NIC"),
                   ("562", "Niger", "NER"),
                   ("566", "Nigeria", "NGA"),
                   ("570", "Niue", "NIU"),
                   ("574", "Norfolk Island", "NFK"),
                   ("580", "Northern Mariana Islands", "MNP"),
                   ("578", "Norway", "NOR"),
                   ("512", "Oman", "OMN"),
                   ("586", "Pakistan", "PAK"),
                   ("585", "Palau", "PLW"),
                   ("591", "Panama", "PAN"),
                   ("598", "Papua New Guinea", "PNG"),
                   ("600", "Paraguay", "PRY"),
                   ("604", "Peru", "PER"),
                   ("608", "Philippines", "PHL"),
                   ("612", "Pitcairn", "PCN"),
                   ("616", "Poland", "POL"),
                   ("620", "Portugal", "PRT"),
                   ("630", "Puerto Rico", "PRI"),
                   ("634", "Qatar", "QAT"),
                   ("410", "Republic of Korea", "KOR"),
                   ("498", "Republic of Moldova", "MDA"),
                   ("638", "Réunion", "REU"),
                   ("642", "Romania", "ROU"),
                   ("643", "Russian Federation", "RUS"),
                   ("646", "Rwanda", "RWA"),
                   ("652", "Saint Barthélemy", "BLM"),
                   ("654", "Saint Helena", "SHN"),
                   ("659", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "KNA"),
                   ("662", "Saint Lucia", "LCA"),
                   ("663", "Saint Martin (French part)", "MAF"),
                   ("666", "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "SPM"),
                   ("670", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "VCT"),
                   ("882", "Samoa", "WSM"),
                   ("674", "San Marino", "SMR"),
                   ("678", "Sao Tome and Principe", "STP"),
                   ("680", "Sark", " "),
                   ("682", "Saudi Arabia", "SAU"),
                   ("686", "Senegal", "SEN"),
                   ("688", "Serbia", "SRB"),
                   ("690", "Seychelles", "SYC"),
                   ("694", "Sierra Leone", "SLE"),
                   ("702", "Singapore", "SGP"),
                   ("534", "Sint Maarten (Dutch part)", "SXM"),
                   ("703", "Slovakia", "SVK"),
                   ("705", "Slovenia", "SVN"),
                   ("90", "Solomon Islands", "SLB"),
                   ("706", "Somalia", "SOM"),
                   ("710", "South Africa", "ZAF"),
                   ("728", "South Sudan", "SSD"),
                   ("724", "Spain", "ESP"),
                   ("144", "Sri Lanka", "LKA"),
                   ("275", "State of Palestine", "PSE"),
                   ("729", "Sudan", "SDN"),
                   ("740", "Suriname", "SUR"),
                   ("744", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands", "SJM"),
                   ("748", "Swaziland", "SWZ"),
                   ("752", "Sweden", "SWE"),
                   ("756", "Switzerland", "CHE"),
                   ("760", "Syrian Arab Republic", "SYR"),
                   ("762", "Tajikistan", "TJK"),
                   ("764", "Thailand", "THA"),
                   ("807", "The former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia", "MKD"),
                   ("626", "Timor-Leste", "TLS"),
                   ("768", "Togo", "TGO"),
                   ("772", "Tokelau", "TKL"),
                   ("776", "Tonga", "TON"),
                   ("780", "Trinidad and Tobago", "TTO"),
                   ("788", "Tunisia", "TUN"),
                   ("792", "Turkey", "TUR"),
                   ("795", "Turkmenistan", "TKM"),
                   ("796", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "TCA"),
                   ("798", "Tuvalu", "TUV"),
                   ("800", "Uganda", "UGA"),
                   ("804", "Ukraine", "UKR"),
                   ("784", "United Arab Emirates", "ARE"),
                   ("826", "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", "GBR"),
                   ("834", "United Republic of Tanzania", "TZA"),
                   ("840", "United States of America", "USA"),
                   ("850", "United States Virgin Islands", "VIR"),
                   ("858", "Uruguay", "URY"),
                   ("860", "Uzbekistan", "UZB"),
                   ("548", "Vanuatu", "VUT"),
                   ("862", "Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)", "VEN"),
                   ("704", "Viet Nam", "VNM"),
                   ("876", "Wallis and Futuna Islands", "WLF"),
                   ("732", "Western Sahara", "ESH"),
                   ("887", "Yemen", "YEM"),
                   ("894", "Zambia", "ZMB"),
                   ("716", "Zimbabwe", "ZWE"),
                   ("000", "000", "UNK")]

    @property
    def count(self):
        return len(self.UN)

    @property
    def UN_Codes(self):
        codes = [int(a[0]) for a in self.UN]
        return codes

    @property
    def Str_Codes(self):
        return [a[2] for a in self.UN]

    def getby_int(self, un_code_as_int):
        '''
        Look up UN code using integer i.e. Oman is 512
        :param un_code_as_int:
        :return:
        '''
        for ctry in self.UN:
            if int(ctry[0]) == un_code_as_int:
                return nation(ctry[0], ctry[1], ctry[2])
        return self.UN[:-1]

    def getby_code(self, un_code_as_code):
        '''
        Look up UN code using integer i.e. Oman is OMN
        :param un_code_as_code:
        :return: Tuple containing (Integer Code, String Code, Country Name)
        All return items are strings
        '''

        un_code_as_code = un_code_as_code.upper().lstrip().rstrip()

        for ctry in self.UN:
            if ctry[0] == un_code_as_code:
                return nation(ctry[0], ctry[1], ctry[2])
        return self.UN[:-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [`validate_country()`](https://docs.dataprep.ai/user_guide/clean/clean_country.html) from the library [DataPrep](https://dataprep.ai/). Install it with `pip install dataprep`.

`validate_country()` returns True if the value is a valid country and False otherwise.

```py
from dataprep.clean import validate_country
df = pd.DataFrame({"column1": ["Hong Kong", "United States of America",
     "Malaysia", "Thailand", "Canada", "Indi", "Koreai", "Japan", "Australia"]})
srs = validate_country(df["column1"])
srs
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7     True
8     True
Name: column1, dtype: bool
```

So to print only the invalid countries, you can index the DataFrame with the output of `validate_country()`:

```py
df["column1"][~validate_country(df["column1"])]
5      Indi
6    Koreai
Name: column1, dtype: object
```